# The tag [calibration]

Tags: discussion, tags

From its excerpt:

> Calibration can refer to predicting an explanatory variable from an observation of the dependent variable; to adjustment of measurements to agree with value of some standard; to transform classifier scores into class membership probabilities; etc.

These are quite unrelated uses sharing the same tag, only for language reasons. Especially the first mentioned use, inverse prediction, is quite unrelated to other uses. Should we split this and introduce a new tag 'inverse-prediction' (or in some other way)?

Comment: The "inverse prediction" bit is *directly related* to 'adjustment of measurements' to (agree with some standard). Those first two items are not separate things at all. To me the third thing is much more of an outlier.

Comment: Should [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622188) which is basically adjusting quality scores for referee bias, have the tag `inverse-prediction`, `calibration` or both?

Comment: `inverse-prediction` seems to be a lesser known concept as such, so people will likely not google this term, but rather "calibration". But once it is known, it is nice not to have to wade through all the unrelated `calibration` posts